# Install Two builds of a project in emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have two Builds taken from a single project of Windows Phone 7.1.I want to install both the XAPS to the Emulator(or device).Problem I am Facing now is when one build is installed to the emulator the other vanishes.Should I need to change anythng in properties Plz guide me.

Comment: Why you need to install 2 proyects? they both live on Separate Isolated Storage... Are you working with a background agent?

Comment: I need to install 2 builds taken from a same project(Each build having different characteristics)

Comment: Well that's is simply not possible on the 7.1 emulator, you can install up to 3 developer instance on a developer unlock device the only situation that i have feel the need of installing 2 projects on the same device and same deploy is when working with background agents (code that runs while the app is not on screen)

My recommendation will be to use and deploy under different emulators or a DEVICE

Comment: Maybe you can find a hack, but so far i haven't found anything

Comment: You misunderstood my question.What I want to know is "Is it possible to deploy an xap(same xap) to a device or emulator two times(by changing something in the properties of project or anyway)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside *Properties* => *WMAppManifest.xaml* (or similar name)

`<App xmlns="" ProductID="{77a80316-384d-40dc-a8c3-c4054676e85c}" />`
Change the product ID.

I have never try this manualy, but it should work.

Comment: That will work. Product IDs have to be different for each project in solution. I had this problem today :)

Comment: FYI, you can specify the name of the WMAppManifest.xaml file as an MSBuild property so you could (in theory) have another csproj that imports the your main csproj and then changes the WMAppManifest.xaml property. More complex to setup, but it should simplify ongoing testing.